# Java in pyspark

Tags: python, jdbc, pyspark

I'm new with pyspark. Right now I'm having a problem with connecting to postgresql. This is my code

```
import os
import sys
import findspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import upper
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_path = r"D:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\longnv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark" # spark installed folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_path
findspark.init()

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "D:/Programs/postgresql-42.2.23.jar").getOrCreate()
```

The result is not what I expected:

```
Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I have tried to use only `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()` and I see no error. I even can create some df and test some functions with that Session. But when I add jars into it, the code just doesn't work.

Comment: What is your `java` version

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: are you using `windows` or `linux`

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: is your `JAVA_HOME` env variable set properly?

Comment: I set it: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_291 (Java folder)